# Difference between !condition and variable != otherVariable in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I am sure I am missing some JavaScript fundamentals here but can anyone help me understand why these evaluate differently? The last line.

```
$("input[name=myGroup]").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        if ($(this).val() != "Customers") { //do the stuff...
```

and

```
$("input[name=myGroup]").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        if (!$(this).val() == "Customers") { //do the stuff
```

In my particular instance I thought they would both evaluate to true and "do the stuff". But it seems that only the first block actually evaluates to what I thought.

After looking on MDN to try to gain some insight into comparison operators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators 
vs 
the use of logical operators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators but I still don't quite understand why they yield different results. Thanks.

Comment: PLEASE use != or !== instead. `!....... == ......` is wrong, and `!($....... == ......)` unreadable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Order of operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) matters. `!` is before `==`, so

```
!$(this).val() == "Customers"
```

is treated as

```
false == "Customers"
```

which returns `false`, of course. Try using

```
!($(this).val() === "Customers")
```

instead: notice the explicit parentheses. I also used the strict equality operator (`===` instead of `==`) so that type is also compared.

Of course, just using

```
$(this).val() !== "Customers"
```

works perfectly fine, and is the most readable.

Comment: No, don't do `!(... === ...)`. Use `!==`. That's what it's for. Putting the `!` at the beginning inverting the main operator is just asking for maintenance hassles when people miss the `!`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't want the OP to actually use `!(... === ...)`; I wanted them to test it out for demonstration purposes. But I've clarified my answer.

Comment: @ mc10: Ah, okay. :-) That "Try using" read to me like "Try using this in your code instead".

Comment: @mc10 Order of Operations says it all! Thank you. I am not coming from a CS background I am more self-taught so I tried to make this as intelligible as possible. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

1. `!x == y`

   - This means test *LHS* `NOT(ToBool(x))` is similar to *RHS* `y`
   - Therefore *LHS* will always evaluate to `true` or `false` before being tested against `y`
   - `bool == string` is usually `false`

     - If `ToNumber(string)` is `1` and `bool` is `true`, it returns `true`
     - If `ToNumber(string)` is `0` and `bool` is `false`, it returns `true`
     - Otherwise returns `false`
2. `x != y`

   - This means test *LHS* `x` is similar to *RHS* `y`, then do `NOT(result)`
   - You can rewrite this as `!(x == y)`

So the difference between the two is that the `NOT` is applied **only** to the *LHS* in *1*, and in *2* it is only applied **after** a `==` test.

---

I call `==` ***similar to*** because it is an [**abstract equality**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) comparison. If you want to test explicitly, you may wish to use `===` or it's negation, `!==`, which is a [**strict equality**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6) comparison.